# How do I export Active Directory membership?

Tags: windows, active-directory

I am in an organization with thousands of users and some of them are not in the correct Active Directory group. I can access most of the groups through dsquery `Rundll dsquery.dll OpenQueryWindow`, but the way the groups are configured, it takes forever to check. Microsoft doesn't provide any information I've seen to export this to a text file or other source, but there must be a better way to get this information.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean organizational unit (OU) instead of group.

Use PowerShell. You do need [RSAT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2693643) installed. Then you can run:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "ou=testou,dc=iammred,dc=net"
```

Change the OU to the OU you want to look at.

Or if you really did mean group:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -identity "GROUPNAME" -Recursive
```